# gdb /x command on var vs *var

Tags: c, gdb

I am learning GDB. When I run the x /3b command to see a 3-byte char array, I get two different outputs depending on if I put a * before the array name.

```
(gdb) x /3b myThreeCharArray
0x7fffffffe3c0: 4   11  64
(gdb) x /3b *myThreeCharArray
0x400b04 <debug>:   85  72  -119
```

What the difference between these two outputs? My understanding is that the x command will show you the bytes in memory represented by a particular variable. So I guess I thought that the x command inherently "dereferences" the variable name, but apparently that is not the case. What's going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `gdb` the x command takes an address and attempts to print values from that memory location. So in the second case you dereference `myThreeCharArray` and produce a value which `gdb` interprets as an address and attempts to print the memory at that "location". You can see this is the case if you convert your first 3 numbers to hex:

```
64 is 0x40
11 is 0x0B
04 is 0x04
```

The order is switched because of endianness.